# IIS Rewrite Rule to enforce Language

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a website which is only offered in a single language today.  I am branching out to multiple languages (us english and mexico spanish), and need to redirect all old URLs to their new language equivalent in us english.

That is, I am looking to redirect URLs in this manner:

```
Old URL                  New URL                  Reasoning
mysite.com/              mysite.com/us/en         Redirect no language to language
mysite.com/about         mysite.com/us/en/about   Redirect no language to language
mysite.com/mx/es         mysite.com/mx/es         No change, language should be ignored
mysite.com/us/en/about   mysite.com/us/en/about   No change, language should be ignored
```

I am looking at doing this with a URL Rewrite rule in IIS.

I have this rule created, but it's not behaving correctly.

```
    <rule name="Force Language" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(?!((\/us\/en)|(\/mx\/es)))(.*)$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{REQUEST_URI}us/en{R:1}" redirectType="Found"/>
    </rule>
```

The root hit (e.g., mysite.com) is redirecting, but anything with a path is not redirecting.  What am I missing?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below url rule:

```
<rule name="test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*" />
       <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/us/en/{R:0}" redirectType="Found" />
   <conditions>
       <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(us|mx)/(en|es)" negate="true" />
   </conditions>
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize you can use the negate operator like this!